# Non-existent PDF for combined MixtureDistribution and TransformedDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to mix two discrete distributions, one of them shifted by an integer amount by means of TransformedDistribution. When I then try to access the mix, it responds to CDF but not PDF. This does not happen if I simply mix two discrete distributions.

```
pDist := BinomialDistribution[4, 0.6];
pDist2 := BinomialDistribution[10, 0.3];
tDist := TransformedDistribution[2 + w, w \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[5, 0.4]];
mDist := MixtureDistribution[{0.3, 0.7}, {pDist, tDist}];
mDist2 := MixtureDistribution[{0.3, 0.7}, {pDist, pDist2}];

DiscretePlot[PDF[pDist, t], {t, 0, 8}, Filling -> Bottom]
DiscretePlot[PDF[pDist2, t], {t, 0, 8}, Filling -> Bottom]
DiscretePlot[PDF[tDist, t], {t, 0, 8}, Filling -> Bottom]
DiscretePlot[PDF[mDist, t], {t, 0, 8}, Filling -> Bottom]
DiscretePlot[PDF[mDist2, t], {t, 0, 8}, Filling -> Bottom]

DiscretePlot[CDF[mDist, t], {t, 0, 8}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image: PDF plots: mix with transformed does not work]

[image: CDF plot for transformed works just fine]

Comment: What version are you using? On version 10.2 I don't see this.

Comment: 10.2.0.0 for Mac OS X

Comment: I'm running on OS X as well. Interesting. Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: I get the same results on 10.1.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.